# Como alterar o título, legenda, filtro e exportar o Mapa em pdf usando o leaflet no R?

Tags: r, leaflet

Criei um mapa de MG para identificar a qtde de consultas por município mineiro. Consegui o código abaixo na internet e deu certo. Porém gostaria de acrescentar mais algumas informações, mas não estou conseguindo. São elas:

1) Colocar o título do gráfico na parte superior do mapa (ou se possível, desmontar como faço para movimentá-lo).

2) Inserir uma legenda com as escalas de cores, por exemplo (de 0 a 500 consultas um tom claro de azul; de 501 a 1000 consultas um tom mais escuro de azul e assim por diante etc)

3) Como o meu interesse é apenas nos municípios de MG, seria possível aparecer, no resultado, apenas o mapa de MG ao invés de todo o mapa mundial?

4) Como faço para exportar o mapa para pdf?

Código usado para fazer o gráfico:

```
pal <- colorBin("Blues",domain = NULL,n=5) #cores do mapa

state_popup <- paste0("<strong>Município: </strong>", 
                      MUNICIPIOS_MG$NM_MUNICIP, 
                      "<br><strong> Qtde Consultas Eletivas: </strong>", 
                      MUNICIPIOS_MG$QTD_CONSULTAS)
leaflet(data = MUNICIPIOS_MG) %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  addPolygons(fillColor = ~pal(MUNICIPIOS_MG$QTD_CONSULTAS), 
              fillOpacity = 0.9, 
              color = "#BDBDC3", 
              weight = 1, 
              popup = state_popup) %>%
  addLegend("bottomright", pal = pal, values = ~MUNICIPIOS_MG$QTD_CONSULTAS,
            title = "QUANTIDADE DE CONSULTAS ELETIVAS",
            opacity = 1)
```

Obrigado.